# Video Should not Play every time when page loads and page reloads in a SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, 2016, html5, script-editor-webpart

In SharePoint default page I add script editor web-part and in this added below script

```
<video width="100%" autoplay="false" controls="true" style="width: 100%;">
        <source src="../../Style%20Library/Video/Video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />

        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
```

Here I don't want Video Play every time when page loads and page reloads only when user click the play button.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `autoplay` attribute like:

```
<video width="100%" controls style="width: 100%;">
    <source src="../../Style%20Library/Video/Video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />

    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

> To disable video autoplay, `autoplay="false"` will not work; the video will autoplay if the attribute is there in the `<video>` tag at all. To remove autoplay, the attribute needs to be removed altogether.

**Source**: [autoplay attribute documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-autoplay)